# Where is a Response transformed into one of its subclasses?

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to write a downloader middleware that ignores responses that don't have a pre-defined element. However, I can't use the `css` method of the HtmlResponse class inside the middleware because, at that point, the response's type is just `Response`. When it reaches the spider it's an HtmlResponse, but then it's too late because I can't perform certain actions to the middleware state.

Where is the response's final type set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code of the middleware it is hard to tell what the matter is.

However my middleware below gets an `HtmlResponse` object:

```
class FilterMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        print response.__class__
        print type(response)
        return response**strong text**
```

Both print statements verify this:

```
<class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'>
<class 'scrapy.http.response.html.HtmlResponse'>
```

And I can use the `css` method on the response without any exception. The order of the middleware in the `settings.py` does not matter either: with 10, 100 or 500 I get the same result as above.

**However** if I configure the middleware to *590* or above I get plain old `Response` object. And this is because the conversion happens in the **`HttpCompressionMiddleware`** class on line *35* in [the current version](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpcompression.py).

To solve your issue order your middleware somewhere later on the pipeline (with a lower order number) or convert the response yourself (I would not do this however).

Comment: Of course, when the response comes back the middlewares are executed from higher to lower. It seems that I wasn't thinking clearly last night :)
I'll verify this tonight and accept the answer.

Comment: I hope it worked out for good. Late night thinking can become too complex sometimes ;)